# Presto - Query ... No worker nodes available

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-emr, presto

Using Amazon EMR, Hive .13, Hadoop 2.x, and Presto Server 0.89.  Trying to set up Presto to query data that is usually queried through Hive.  Hive metadata is stored in MySQL. Presto Server is installed set up on all nodes.  For the most part everything is set up as is documented on prestodb.io.

I first start the server on all nodes (coordinator and workers), and then start the CLI on the coordinator/name node.  When I try to run a query using the below commands I get a "Query ... No worker nodes available" error:

```
presto-cli presto-cli --server localhost:8080 --catalog jmx --schema default 
presto:default> SELECT * FROM sys.node;
"Query ... No worker nodes available"
```

If I include the `node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true` in my coordinator config.properties file, 1 node is returned from this query.

Configs:

**etc/config.properties (only on coordinator)**

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=8080
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://aws.internal.ip.of.coordinator:8080
```

**etc/config.properties (only on workers)**

```
coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=8080
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery.uri=http://aws.internal.ip.of.coordinator:8080
```

**etc/catalog/hive.properties (all nodes)**

```
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://aws.internal.ip.of.coordinator:9083
```

**etc/catalog/jmx.properties (all nodes)**

```
connector.name=jmx
```

**etc/jvm.config (all nodes)**

```
-server
-Xmx16G
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=150M
```

**etc/log.properties**

```
com.facebook.presto=INFO
```

**etc/node.properties**

```
node.environment=production
node.id=unique-uuid #used uuidgen
node.data-dir=/mnt/presto-data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake on my part was making this not run.  I had a random semi-colon instead of a period in my `aws.internal.ip.of.coordinator` IP address.  Looking at my configs I just didn't see it.

The above code will work on an Amazon EMR multi-node cluster similar to the one above.